# Is it possible to create a Qt/C++ app which hosts some widgets provided through a pyqt/pyside script?

Tags: c++, qt, pyqt, pyside

I am working on a C++/Qt5 project. There are some reasons that I have to build the framework with native C++/Qt instead of PyQt/PySide.However, I also want the app to have the ability to load UI and corresponding logic dynamically.

Naturally, I think it would be great if I could write a simple Python script that creates a few widgets, makes the main framework to load the script, and puts the aforementioned widgets somewhere in the main window (which is created and managed from the C++ side).

I do found some posts about this, e.g.:

[Embeding PySide/PyQt widget into Qt/C++ application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22553642/embeding-pyside-pyqt-widget-into-qt-c-application) (The code won't work as I had commented, but the authors are not there)

[Call pyqt widget from Qt widgets application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55685163/call-pyqt-widget-from-qt-widgets-application?rq=3) (there seems only a QDialog, no widget exchange)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SylgpRc-Lrg&t=1366s (there is an interesting presentation, but the code on C++ side is not available)

I know it is barely possible to have unlimited interaction between the C++ side and PyQt/PySide (like `connect` a C++ slot function to a PyQt widget), but is there any practical way to make simple interaction like UI integration?

Comment: Are you forced to use QWidgets, or is QML an option?

Comment: @hyde There's some CAD module, so QML is not an option.

Comment: Did you test it does not work? https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qquickwidget.html Because if it does work, it solves all your problems. Exposing C++ data (either QObjects with properties, or QAbstractItemModel subclasses) to QML is trivial and well documented.

Comment: I am not familiar with QML, but I think it's unacceptable to rewrite the app using QML. Compared to QML, rewriting the app using PyQt is not that hard ...

Comment: You might want to clarify the question then, and explain more explicitly that you already have a bunch of widgets, and want to enable creating UI from these widgets from Python (or whatever the actual constraints/requirements are).

Comment: Another alternative to explore would be to allow desiging the widgets with the Designer, creating .ui files which are loaded at runtime. But writing UI logic this way needs some creativity and is probably tedious, so feasibility depends on just how complex logic you want. Can you write a fixed logic evaluation/execution in C++, and just have properties in the .ui file, determining what happens?

Comment: [PythonQt](https://mevislab.github.io/pythonqt/)?

Comment: @hyde Loading '*.ui' dynamically would partly achieve my goal, but as you have said, the C++ part would be hard, and it will require also loading other data to achieve functions like real-time input validation.

Comment: @ekhumoro I tried PythonQt and it is one of the possibilities, but the python-side of PythonQt seems not compatible with PyQt or PySide. You do build UI dynamically via Python scripts, but loading ready-made PyQt code is not supported. From another perspective, since PythonQt needs to be developed, it may not be feasible to side-load PyQt code from C++ through a simple way.